# Failed to fetch after restarting server

Tags: javascript, html, express

So I'm making a website and I made a login function, For some reason when I make an account and try to login it works, but when I restart the server it says "failed to fetch" I don't know what could be changing

function validation

```js
function validation(email, password) {
    let data = `{
"email": "${email}",
"password": "${password}"
}`;
alert(data)
    fetch("https://domain/api/user/get", {
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": data
        })
        .then(async response => {
            response.json().then(json => {
               if (json.error.isError == true) {
                    document.getElementById('invalid').style.borderColor='red'
                    document.getElementById('invalid').style.visibility = 'visible'
                    document.getElementById('invalid').style.opacity = '1'
                    return document.getElementById('invalid').innerText = json.error.message
                    // return false;
                }
                location.href='/dashboard'
            });
        }).catch(e => {
          alert(e)
          return false;
          })
}
```

function login

```js
function login() {
  try {
    let email = document.getElementById('nemail').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('npassword').value;
    var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
        return false;
    }
    validation(email, password);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
  }
}
```

app post

```
app.post("/api/user/get", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let {email, password} = req.body

    if (!email) {
      eValid = '{"error": {"isError": true, "message": "No Email Provided"}}'
        return res.send(eValid)
    }

    if (!password) {
      eValid = '{"error": {"isError": true, "message": "No password provided"}}'
      return res.send(eValid)
    }
  if(email) {
      var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
      if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
        eValid = '{"error": {"isError": true, "message": "Invalid Email"}}'
      return res.send(eValid)
      } 
    }
    const userData = await userdb.findOne({email: email});

    if (!userData) {
      eValid = '{"error": {"isError": true, "message": "Account Not found. Is the Email correct?"}}'
        return res.send(eValid)
    }
  let hashMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userData.password)
    if(!hashMatch) {
      eValid = '{"error": {"isError": true, "message": "Password is Incorrect. Please Try Again."}}'
      return res.send(eValid)
    }
  eValid = '{"error": {"isError": false, "message": null}}'
  req.session.isAuth = true;
  console.log("it gets here at least")
  return res.send(eValid)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})
```

I don't know what I might be doing wrong D: If you guys could help that would be nice, I've tried console logging where it gets and trying to log it in but I don't know why it's throwing that error or why it works when I sign up for the first time. And sorry if the code Is a bit messy I know people get mad about that

Comment: Failed to fetch after restarting server. Did you check if your server started properly. Because if the code working once it should work not matter how many times server gets restarted. And your code seems to be fine

Comment: The server seems to be starting fine. it also seems to be after the account has been logged into once. It could be something with cookies so I'm going to try removing cookies to see if that works!

Comment: Also check if you are setting any kind of flags in the DB.

Comment: So it does seem like it was to do with the cookies, So for now I won't use cookies until I find out what the problem could be.